# Select more columns with MAX function

Tags: sql

Need to find in databse max value, but then i need read other values in columns.

Can this be done with one SQL command or I have to use this two commands?

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table; 
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = $value;
```

where $value is variable from 1st command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where id = (select max(id) from your_table)
```

or

```
select t1.* from your_table t1
inner join 
(
   select max(id) as mid 
   from your_table 
) 
t2 on t1.id = t2.mid
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is:

```
select *
from t
order by id
limit 1
```

Or use `top 1` or `where rownum = 1` or whatever is the right logic for your database.

Note:  this only returns one row.  If you have duplicate such rows, then comparison to the maximum will give you all of them.

Also, if you are using a database that supports window functions:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```